# Как правильнее сделать оперирование переменной из одного скрипта в другом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется вот такой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrabbableFlowerBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject Player;
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find(Player);
    Player PCntrl = go.GetComponent<FlowerCount>();
    public int FC = PCntrl.FlowerCount;
    private GameObject GrabbableFlower;
    private float f = 0.0f;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)

    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            FC++;
            Destroy(GrabbableFlower, .0f);

        }

    }

}
```

Я не понимаю, почему Unity выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Assets\scripts\GrabbableFlowerBehavior.cs(9,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [Скрипт (сценарий)](https://www.russianpromo.ru/wiki/script/#:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B-,%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B,%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5.) — это последовательность действий, описанных с помощью **скриптового** языка программирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObject.Find ищет объект по имени, имя это строка, а строки заключаются в кавычки.
Поэтому мы замените GameObject.Find(Player) на GameObject.Find("Player")